# can registration be enabled programatically?

Tags: user-registration

I need to allow registration as part of a build for a client, and I am aware this can be turned on in the admin panel, but can I turn it on in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes sure you can, just update the appropriate option inside your given function..

```
update_option( 'users_can_register', 1 );
```

It's a checkbox option, so the value is 1 = on, 0 = off..

Hope that helps..

Comment: excellent, now can I remove the setting from the admin panel?

Comment: Since you've posted the follow-up as another question i've answered there.. :)